# Kotlin lateinit correspondent java

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Hello when I use Kotlin to program Android I have seen `lateinit` in the code. What is the equivalent in java？ How can I change this code from Kotlin to Java?

```
public class MyTest {
    lateinit var subject: TestSubject
}
```

Comment: Just use java `getter`, in which you check if it is initialized, if not create one

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`lateinit` in Kotlin is there so that you can have non-nullable types on variables that you can't initialize at the moment the class containing them is created.

Using your example, if you didn't use `lateinit`, you'd have to make the `subject` nullable, since it has to be initialized with a value.

```
public class MyTest {
    var subject: TestSubject? = null
}
```

This would force you to do null checks every time you use it, which is ugly, so you can mark it as `lateinit` instead.

---

In Java, you don't really have this problem, since everything is nullable, and declaring an uninitialized field is nothing special:

```
public class JavaTest {
    TestSubject subject;
}
```

This initializes `subject` to `null`, so it's practically equivalent to the non-`lateinit` Kotlin example.

The only real difference between the `lateinit` version in Kotlin and the Java version is that you get a more specific exception when trying to access an uninitialized property in Kotlin, namely, a `UninitializedPropertyAccessException`, which will make debugging it easier than having to look for the cause of a generic `NullPointerException`.

---

If you really wanted this slightly different behavior, you could wrap your Java properties in some sort of wrappers, but I don't think it would be worth the syntactic overhead to do so. A very basic (not thread safe, for example) way to do this would be:

Have a generic wrapper class for properties:

```
public class Property<T> {

    private T value = null;

    public T get() {
        if (value == null)
            throw new UninitializedPropertyAccessException("Property has not been initialized");
        return value;
    }

    public void set(T value) {
        if (value == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value can't be null");
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Use this wrapper in your classes:

```
public class JavaTest {
    Property<TestSubject> subject = new Property<>();
}
```

And then this usage would give you the uninitialized exception:

```
JavaTest test = new JavaTest();
test.subject.get();
```

And this one would run fine:

```
JavaTest test = new JavaTest();
test.subject.set(new TestSubject());
test.subject.get();
```

---

**Edit:** this is very similar to how `lateinit` works in Kotlin, if you decompile the bytecode of your example to Java, this is what you get:

```
public final class MyTest {
   @NotNull
   public TestSubject subject;

   @NotNull
   public final TestSubject getSubject() {
      TestSubject var10000 = this.subject;
      if(this.subject == null) {
         Intrinsics.throwUninitializedPropertyAccessException("subject");
      }
      return var10000;
   }

   public final void setSubject(@NotNull TestSubject var1) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(var1, "<set-?>");
      this.subject = var1;
   }
}
```

Basically, the compiler puts the code for checking the property access inside the class itself (+ uses some helper methods) instead of using a wrapper, which is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such property in Java which delays the initialization of property. But I think the behavior in Kotlin and Java are quite similar.

Here are my two cents :

In Kotlin accessing a lateinit property before it has been initialized throws a special exception that clearly identifies the property being accessed and the fact that it hasn't been initialized. (Reference : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html).

In Java also, NullPointerException(NPE) is thrown that indicated that property being accessed is Null.

The only difference could be that, NPE is a runtime exception.

Comment: `UninitializedPropertyAccessException` is also a runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

There are many [examples here](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/yet-another-kotlin-vs-java-comparison). In your case:

```
public class MyTest {
    lateinit var subject: TestSubject
}
```

It compiles to the following Java code:

```
import kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public final class MyTest {
  @NotNull public TestSubject subject;

  @NotNull
  public final TestSubject getSubject() {
    TestSubject testSubject = this.subject;
    if (testSubject == null) {
      Intrinsics.throwUninitializedPropertyAccessException((String) "subject");
    }
    return testSubject;
  }

  public final void setSubject(@NotNull TestSubject testSubject) {
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull((Object) testSubject, (String) "<set-?>");
    this.subject = testSubject;
  }
}
```